# How to get total album size in iPhone?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I know How to get size of a single UIImage, how can I get the Total size of the iPhone Photo Album?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the file size album url.
2. Use fast enumerator to loop through the list of images.
3. Store the images in an array list.
4. Get the file size in bytes and convert it to your liking using below

unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:someFilePath error:nil] fileSize];

Comment: For **Step 1**, how to get the album url, could you tell me specificly